# Is the phrase "full bloodied punch" a common expression?

Tags: phrases, expressions

What does the British expression "full bloodied punch" mean?

Comment: As in:  "He hit him a full bloodied kidney punch."

Comment: I wouldn't call it 'a British expression'. If it was indeed spelled that way (with an 'i'), it appears to be a pun on 'full-blooded' in the sense of vigorous or forceful, hinting that the punch drew blood.

Comment: I think it doesn't at all. I stand to be corrected and I think what you're  asking about is not *full blooded* but *full bodied*…"

Comment: Without a checkable source, this question is not really answerable. The term 'full-blooded' (meaning 'having all one's power put into it; without holding back'), defined in most dictionaries, would fit, but this then becomes general reference.